# How to recover a broken mp4 file: moov atom not found

Tags: audio, data-recovery, video, ffmpeg, mplayer

I made a recording with

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i plughw:0,0  /tmp/audio.mp4
```

I then moved `/tmp/audio.mp4` to another directory (`/root/audio.mp4`) without stopping `ffmpeg` leading to a broken `.mp4` file:

```
ffplay /root/audio.mp4
[...]
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f3524000b80] moov atom not found
audio.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

**How to recover and read my `.mp4` file?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try and use [Untrunc](https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) to fix the file.

> Restore a damaged (truncated) mp4, m4v, mov, 3gp video. Provided you
>   have a similar not broken video.

you may need to compile it from source, but there is another option to use a Docker container and bind the folder with the file into the container and fix it that way.

You can use the included Dockerfile to build and execute the package as a container

```
git clone https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc.git
cd untrunc
docker build -t untrunc .
docker run -v ~/Desktop/:/files untrunc /files/filea /files/fileb
```

Comment: The Untrunc in the repository provided doesn't compile in Ubuntu 18.04 because of "track.cpp:57:11: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory".  But this fork do compile.  https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc

Comment: Since I found this via google (and I'm aware this is the Unix SE), I'd like to add a *Windows* program to do this: https://www.videohelp.com/software/recover-mp4-to-h264

Comment: Actually, the anthwlock fork linked by @HD189733b above is supposed to work in Windows as well, even includes a GUI. I don't use windows so I can't say more on the matter. It works amazing on Ubuntu 18.04 though.

Comment: To avoid the problem with the missing config.h you can use this fork https://github.com/anthwlock/untrunc which does not rely of private libav libraries.

Answer (score 10):

Solution provided here (https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc) solved my problem!
I run it as a Docker container. Here my steps:

- Install Docker (in case you don't have it yet)
- Clone the repository:

  ```
    git clone https://github.com/ponchio/untrunc
  ```
- On the same directory of the Dockerfile, run:

  ```
    cd untrunc
    docker build -t untrunc .
  ```
- That will build a local docker image - it takes time.
- Now you have to provide a sample file from the same origin (in my case the same camera) and the corrupted file you wanna fix. E.g.:

  ```
    docker run -v /path/to/files/:/files untrunc /files/working_video /files/broken_video
  ```

Comment: Doesn't work. Maybe because my videos have different length? I created one video from the other but had to cancel the video generation because it took to long. I guess the canceling while creating the video was the problem. can untrunc fix that too?

Comment: Hi @mcExchange,
If you stop the recovering process the same thing will happen to the fixed video.. let it run until the end.